# How do I get value of fanpages 'like' date?

Tags: php, facebook

I want to get value of Fan Pages likes per day from facebook API by gettinng info about 'like' create time. I am using this:

```
me?fields=id,name,likes{created_time}
```

Somehow it doesn't give me create time data but only info about how much likes Fan Page has.

```
   {
  "id": "12345678",
  "name": "appName",
  "likes": 1
    }
```

How can I know how many likes Fan Page get specific day?

Answer (score 0):

You can only get that kind of information with the Insights API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/insights

Of course you can only access Insights of a Page if you are an Admin of the Page.

Another solution would be to create a Cron Job, get the current Likes every day and store the value in a database.

Comment: thanks, i' m trying now with FB Insights but still theres a problem

when i call '12345678/insights' i get  this in response

 {
  "data": [
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/12345678/insights?debug=all&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1435998094&until=1436257294",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/12345678/insights?debug=all&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1436516494&until=1436775694"
  }
}

where 12345678 is my page id

Comment: and you are sure you got the correct permissions to read the insights?

Comment: I ve created this Fan Pages and i'm admin on this sites, so i think yes.
Should i use some kind of token then? Page Access Token?

Comment: I can't solve it...
When i use (page)access token, i get  similar answer:
For:
https://graph.facebook.com/378301462378708/insights?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
I get response:
{
   "data": [
      
   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/12345678/insights?fields=likes\u00257Bcreated_time\u00257D&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&since=1436102799&until=1436361999",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/12345678/insights?fields=likes\u00257Bcreated_time\u00257D&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&since=1436621199&until=1436880399"
   }
}